# FOR /D terminates with failure (...unexpected at this time)

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file with these lines executed by Jenkins CI job. It should remove all subdirectories in specified directory except two matching IF conditions.

```
SET EXPORT_ROOT=C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder
SET EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT=%EXPORT_ROOT%\build
SET EXPORT_BUILD_PATH=%EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT%\26
SET LAST_EXPORT_BUILD_PATH=C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder\build\25

cd %EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT%
FOR /D %G IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT ("%EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT%\%G" == "%LAST_EXPORT_BUILD_PATH%") IF NOT ("%EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT%\%G" == "%EXPORT_BUILD_PATH%") (
        rd /s /q "%G"
    )
)
cd "%DEPLOY_DIR%"
```

In Jenkins CI log a see:

```
C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder\deploy>cd C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder\build
G" == "C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder\build\57") IF NOT ("EXPORT_BUILD_PATHG" ) ) was unexpected at this time.

C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder\build>FOR /D G" == "C:\WWW\LocalUser\myfolder\build\57") IF NOT ("EXPORT_BUILD_PATHG" ) )
```

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change it more like this:

```bat
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (
    IF /I NOT "%EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT%\%%G"=="%LAST_EXPORT_BUILD_PATH%" (
        IF /I NOT "%EXPORT_BUILD_ROOT%\%%G"=="%EXPORT_BUILD_PATH%" RD/S/Q "%%G")
)
```

The positioning of your parentheses being important as well as the doubling of the **`%`** in a batch file meatvariable.

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR /D %G IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT "%G" == "%LAST_EXPORT_BUILD_PATH%" IF NOT "%G" == "%EXPORT_BUILD_PATH%" (
        rd /s /q "%G"
    )
)
```

Each `%G` referring to the `metavariable` (loop-control variable) must be `%%G`